# Sending a meeting invite in Outlook generates a chain email reaction

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, notifications, exchange-2010

We are currently running an Exchange 2010 environment with Outlook 2010 clients. Here is the scenario.

My boss has allowed the admin staff viewer permissions to his outlook calendar. However, when someone sends him a calendar meeting, everyone who has viewing permissions receives an email regarding that meeting. Likewise, if it is cancelled or altered, everyone receives an update email.

I have removed a couple users from being able to view the calendar to start fresh but they still receive emails regarding his calendar changes. It's as if there is a group setup for the admin staff that no matter if they are connected to his calendar or not, they are still notified.

I've gone through every distribution group in my Exchange and AD and can't find any correlation to what is generating these chain of emails. Are there some settings in Outlook I am overlooking or perhaps in Exchange that is firing these calendar notifications off to our admin staff?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Although the admin staff may have viewer permissions this is likely a red herring. Check whether they are delegates.

Comment: All of the users permissions have been set to viewer.

Comment: What does it say under File | Account Settings| Delegate Access?

Comment: That is the answer. The admin users who had access to his calendar had a checkbox marked "Deliver meeting requests addressed to me and response to meeting requests where I am the organizer to this user." Once I removed the boxes and restarted Outlook, we were good to go.

Answer (score 0):

View permission should not work like this. Check whether they are delegates.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Answer undeleted. OP has confirmed delegate access was the problem.